# Strange c++ memory usage

Tags: c++, memory

I have the follow class:

```
class testclass{
    int a[5];
};
```

and the following main function:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])  
{
    testclass* t;
    while(true)
        t = new testclass();
    return 0;
}
```

So I exected this to just fill up all of my memory really quickly. But this is the memory usage graph that xcode is giving me:

[image]

Which I don't understand at all. How can the memory usage possibly go down in this program?

Comment: Maybe the OS started transferring data to swap?

Comment: probably the OS stopped your app or started allocating directly on swap

Comment: Does that not count as memory usage? Is memory usage really only the amount of data in the actual RAM?

Comment: Make sure that the loop wasn't optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: If it's not optimized out, maybe your library implements new with a memory pool

Comment: If it would be optimized out there wouldn't be any usage at all though right? So it doesn't seem to be optimized out.

Comment: What exactly is the graph showing? What precisely does "memory usage" mean? Physical RAM usage? Virtual address space reserved? Virtual address space mapped (to RAM or to swap file)?

Comment: Yea jalf I think that's exactly the problem. It seems to only be physical RAM, because my virtual mem usage does continue to grow.

Comment: when answering your own question, post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

oke answered. The graph seems to only show physical memory usage. When I go the the activity monitor, I can see that the virtual memory usage is huge:

[image]

That's in dutch but I think you'll understand it.

Thanks for the answers